# How to get certain index range form the array String using vb.net

Tags: .net, arrays

I have a string array with the length of 250 and I need to get a range out of that, i need to get the range from 0 to 189 and the 240 index as a Sub array remaining can be skip. Can i obtain it from without iterating an array

```
Dim data As String() = {"xx", "xx", "xx", "xx", "xx"....... "aa"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer

```
 Dim data1 = data.Take(190)
 Dim data2() As String = data1.ToArray
 data2(190) = data(240)
```